# Printing "\" to system with C not work?

Tags: c

I have coded a little app that does something like the following:

```
sprintf(command, "......sending this string to system......{} \;"
printf("%s\n",command);
system(command);
break;
```

The problem is that not the whole string is sent to system, everything appears in my shell apart from the '\' which doesn't for some reason? I am sure its a silly mistake really, I am a novice.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character (you just used it to print a newline using `\n`), so if you want to print a literal backslash, you need to use `\\`:

```
sprintf(command, "......sending this string to system......{} \\;"
//                                                            ^^
//                                                      take note here
```

Answer (score 0):

\ is an escape character.

to use \, you must preceed \ with another \
like this:

```
\\
```